# Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:

Tags: android, reactjs

I am new react-native and just ran my first hello world app using a real device using Expo.

Now, I would like to run first hello world app on an android emulator. I setup an AVD using AVD Manager from Android Studio. (Marshmallow)

[image]

But, every time the bellow error happens.

I can't find the fix for this.

Any clue is much appreciate.
Mike

```
mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject$ react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/mike/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules (8ms)
03:39:59: Starting packager...
03:44:13: Starting Android...
03:44:18: Packager started!

To view your app with live reloading, point the Expo app to this QR code.
You'll find the QR scanner on the Projects tab of the app.
```

**EDIT**

This is the SS....

[image]

And I get the below error ....

```
mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject$ react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/mike/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject/node_modules (116ms)
21:59:10: Starting packager...
22:03:47: Starting Android...
22:07:47: Packager started!

To view your app with live reloading, point the Expo app to this QR code.
You'll find the QR scanner on the Projects tab of the app.





























Or enter this address in the Expo app's search bar:

  exp://192.168.1.35:19000

Your phone will need to be on the same local network as this computer.
For links to install the Expo app, please visit https://expo.io.

Logs from serving your app will appear here. Press Ctrl+C at any time to stop.

Error running adb: socket hang up
```

The device itself is recognized anyway, so that problem is solved, I just had to fix the path to same ADB as the android studio....see below:

```
mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop$
```

thanks for your comments anyway....

```
Or enter this address in the Expo app's search bar:

  exp://192.168.1.35:19000

Your phone will need to be on the same local network as this computer.
For links to install the Expo app, please visit https://expo.io.

Logs from serving your app will appear here. Press Ctrl+C at any time to stop.

Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.
*** buffer overflow detected ***: adb terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f155e2217e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f155e2c315c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x117160)[0x7f155e2c1160]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1190a7)[0x7f155e2c30a7]
/usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0(_Z11fdevent_setP7fdeventj+0x125)[0x7f155ef2e975]
/usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0(_Z22ss_listener_event_funcijPv+0xcd)[0x7f155ef2533d]
/usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0(_Z12fdevent_loopv+0x94)[0x7f155ef2f144]
adb[0x403de7]
adb[0x404dbe]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f155e1ca830]
adb[0x403889]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00412000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24651269                           /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
00612000-00613000 r--p 00012000 08:05 24651269                           /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
00613000-00614000 rw-p 00013000 08:05 24651269                           /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
00614000-00624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01301000-01333000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f1550000000-7f1550021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1550021000-7f1554000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f15577ff000-7f1557800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1557800000-7f1558000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1558000000-7f1558029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1558029000-7f155c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155c64f000-7f155c650000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155c650000-7f155ce50000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155ce50000-7f155ce51000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155ce51000-7f155d651000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155d651000-7f155d654000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23068876                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f155d654000-7f155d853000 ---p 00003000 08:05 23068876                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f155d853000-7f155d854000 r--p 00002000 08:05 23068876                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f155d854000-7f155d855000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 23068876                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f155d855000-7f155d95d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23068864                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f155d95d000-7f155db5c000 ---p 00108000 08:05 23068864                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f155db5c000-7f155db5d000 r--p 00107000 08:05 23068864                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f155db5d000-7f155db5e000 rw-p 00108000 08:05 23068864                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f155db5e000-7f155db64000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24651263                   /usr/lib/android/liblog.so.0
7f155db64000-7f155dd64000 ---p 00006000 08:05 24651263                   /usr/lib/android/liblog.so.0
7f155dd64000-7f155dd65000 r--p 00006000 08:05 24651263                   /usr/lib/android/liblog.so.0
7f155dd65000-7f155dd66000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 24651263                   /usr/lib/android/liblog.so.0
7f155dd66000-7f155df80000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23073086                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f155df80000-7f155e17f000 ---p 0021a000 08:05 23073086                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f155e17f000-7f155e19b000 r--p 00219000 08:05 23073086                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f155e19b000-7f155e1a7000 rw-p 00235000 08:05 23073086                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f155e1a7000-7f155e1aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155e1aa000-7f155e36a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23068872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f155e36a000-7f155e56a000 ---p 001c0000 08:05 23068872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f155e56a000-7f155e56e000 r--p 001c0000 08:05 23068872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f155e56e000-7f155e570000 rw-p 001c4000 08:05 23068872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f155e570000-7f155e574000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155e574000-7f155e58a000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23073160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f155e58a000-7f155e789000 ---p 00016000 08:05 23073160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f155e789000-7f155e78a000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 23073160                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f155e78a000-7f155e8fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24642822                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f155e8fc000-7f155eafc000 ---p 00172000 08:05 24642822                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f155eafc000-7f155eb06000 r--p 00172000 08:05 24642822                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f155eb06000-7f155eb08000 rw-p 0017c000 08:05 24642822                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f155eb08000-7f155eb0c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155eb0c000-7f155eb16000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24651265                   /usr/lib/android/libcutils.so.0
7f155eb16000-7f155ed15000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 24651265                   /usr/lib/android/libcutils.so.0
7f155ed15000-7f155ed16000 r--p 00009000 08:05 24651265                   /usr/lib/android/libcutils.so.0
7f155ed16000-7f155ed17000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 24651265                   /usr/lib/android/libcutils.so.0
7f155ed17000-7f155ed1b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24651264                   /usr/lib/android/libbase.so.0
7f155ed1b000-7f155ef1a000 ---p 00004000 08:05 24651264                   /usr/lib/android/libbase.so.0
7f155ef1a000-7f155ef1b000 r--p 00003000 08:05 24651264                   /usr/lib/android/libbase.so.0
7f155ef1b000-7f155ef1c000 rw-p 00004000 08:05 24651264                   /usr/lib/android/libbase.so.0
7f155ef1c000-7f155ef3b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 24651266                   /usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0
7f155ef3b000-7f155f13a000 ---p 0001f000 08:05 24651266                   /usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0
7f155f13a000-7f155f13b000 r--p 0001e000 08:05 24651266                   /usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0
7f155f13b000-7f155f13c000 rw-p 0001f000 08:05 24651266                   /usr/lib/android/libadb.so.0
7f155f13c000-7f155f154000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23068870                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f155f154000-7f155f353000 ---p 00018000 08:05 23068870                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f155f353000-7f155f354000 r--p 00017000 08:05 23068870                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f155f354000-7f155f355000 rw-p 00018000 08:05 23068870                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f155f355000-7f155f359000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155f359000-7f155f37f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 23068868                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f155f546000-7f155f54f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155f57d000-7f155f57e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f155f57e000-7f155f57f000 r--p 00025000 08:05 23068868                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f155f57f000-7f155f580000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 23068868                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f155f580000-7f155f581000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd4a004000-7ffd4a026000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd4a109000-7ffd4a10c000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd4a10c000-7ffd4a10e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

**EDIT**

I followed the link in the error message it turns out I had not installed "apt-get install android-tools-adb". So I installed it and then ran when I had two devices connected (an actual Nexus 5 and a AVD Nexus 6.):

```
mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop$ adb devices 
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop$
```

Note that using Expo everything works just fine. I just want to be able to use an emulator (Whether Android or Gynomotion) for the sake of development.

**EDIT**

I managed to connect an actual device using USB. Tried

```
sudo adb kill-server 
sudo adb start-server
```

But, it was very slow ...it took 10mins to show up the app on the device (Nexus 5).

But still having problem with running things on Emulator. It give the below error:

`Error running adb: socket hang up`

**EDIT**

Dear Gavin,

Below is the snapshot of what I have on my Andr. Stdu. ...

I look forward to hearing your comments...
thanks very much indeed

[image]

Comment: Also just confirm I don't use Genymotion to run the ADV.

Answer (score 10):

You need to actually launch your virtual device in android studio. While AS is open, click the emulator (looks like phone) button in the top right, it will launch the emulator if you're setup right, then you can run react-native run-android

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't find the button. Can you  please high light on the screenshot?

Comment: I installed  sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb. But aparantly no device is detected. mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject$ adb devices 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop/react-native/AwesomeProject$

Comment: post a SS of your android studio like I did.

Comment: Sometimes down below in the console, there is a yellow exclamation point that you can click and it will auto fix issues. I had to do this for the first time, then I clicked the emulator button, its the fourth button inwards from the far right. The first picture I posted is what it looks like.

Comment: For some reason (I'm new to RN also) You need to explicitly start your android emulator from android studio via this button. Unlike the ios emulator you can run from simply react-native run-ios

Comment: You should wait for your android emulator to fully "load" and be ready to click around with it before running react-native run-android

Comment: I updated the questions....virtual device is detected finally...I just had PATH var pointing to the incorrect ADB. NO i getting "
Error running adb: socket hang up." thanks for your cooments anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed eventually. I don't know how I did it exactly but I did the below. I may help others too...so I write this for everyone else just let others know.

I upgraded my Ubuntu

```
mike@mike-Laptop:~/Desktop$ uname -a
Linux mike-Laptop 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And then I installed yarn (before I only had npm before)....

And then recreated the AwesomeProject.

And I confirmed every single step mentioned on the getting started page under [Building Projects with Native Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

I hope it helps other too....

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this and resolved it by downloading the expo app from the google play store.  Per https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#running-your-react-native-application and scanning the code from the app.